# Why unload variables in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, environment-variables, cmd.exe

Is it considered necessary or good practice to *unload* variables used in Windows batch files?
For example in the following code, is the `set myFolder=` at the end necessary?

```
@echo off
set myFolder="C:\Temp\Batchfiles"
echo %myFolder%

set myFolder=
```

I have seen this in a number of places online, surely the variables are unloaded automatically when the batch file ends?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`SET` will set a global environment variable. It will persist after the execution of your script.

Let's have a look at an example.
First, I clear the variable to make sure it doesn't exist.

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>set TEST=
```

A quick test:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>echo %TEST%
%TEST%
```

Let's create that batch file and execute it:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>echo set TEST=something>test.bat
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>test.bat
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>set TEST=something
```

Let's see the value of TEST after the execution of my `.bat` file:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>echo %TEST%
something
```

So, yes, clearing the variable at the end of the script is good practice.

---

Even better would be to use [`SETLOCAL`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx) and [`ENDLOCAL`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/endlocal.mspx) to avoid the whole problem.

Here, I created a new `.bat` file that uses `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL`:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>type test.bat
setlocal
set TEST=something
endlocal
```

Let's clear `TEST` and echo it to make sure we start clean:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>set TEST=
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>echo %TEST%
%TEST%
```

Great, now let's run the new `.bat`:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>test.bat
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>setlocal
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>set TEST=something    
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>endlocal
```

Now `TEST` will still be empty:

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop>echo %TEST%
%TEST%
```

Comment: +! for the clarification