# how to access variables that are set in a different windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, environment-variables

i have a windows batch file - called fileA.bat, which contains a variable set in it.
Sample code of fileA.bat:

```
set fileA_username=michael
```

now i have another batch file, called fileB.bat, which needs to access this variable set in fileA.bat.

So the code that I write in fileB.bat would want to do something like this:

```
set fileB_username = %fileA_username%
```

and then keep using the fileB_username in the script code.

FileB would be calling fileA as part of execution like this:

code in fileB:

```
---
---
call fileA.bat
---
---
set fileB_username = fileA_username
---
if fileB_username
----
```

---

how do i access variables that are set in external batch files? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You've got a typo in the variable name: `fielA_username` vs. `fileA_username`, otherwise your code is good. Also you should avoid pretty spaces around `=` sign in `SET` command since they will become a part of variable name and its value (try: `SET foo=bar && SET foo = bar && SET foo`).

---

```
@REM this is setenv.bat

SET ENV=IRON
```

---

```
@REM and this is "main" script

CALL setenv.bat

@REM append something to the value
SET ENV=%ENV%MENT

REM print the current value
SET ENV
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and neat explanation. I got the point now. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @tsum, you can vote and accept if you feel so ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you specify `SETLOCAL` or unset the variable explicitly in batch file A, the variable will be global and accessible to your second batch file.

For further information see [Why unload variables in Windows batch files](https://superuser.com/questions/397047/why-unload-variables-in-windows-batch-files)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. And the link you gave provided a very concise explanation into what I was looking for. Really appreciate your help. Thanks!